# Modifying a numpy index during assignment

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

I am unsure of the correct terminology to search for to find the correct optimisation. I want to simplify the final four lines of code below into two lines, whereby, the addition of `+/- 1` is done during the assignment to `plus` and `minus` variables respectively.

```
    # generic params to simulate loop conditions
    position = np.arange(10)
    axis = 2

    # actual code to optimise
    plus = np.asarray(position)
    plus[axis] += 1
    minus = np.asarray(position)
    minus[axis] -= 1
```

To clarify this is an iteration problem: Any solutions that don't take generic `position` or `axis` variables are wrong i.e. explicitly the following are not solutions:

```
plus = np.asarray([0,1,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
plus = np.asarray(range(axis)+[position[axis]+1]+range(axis+1,len(position)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to *condense* those four lines to two -

```
mask = np.in1d(np.arange(position.size),axis)
plus, minus = position + mask, position - mask
```

**Sample run**

Let's test it out for a generic `position` array with another index `6` -

```
In [60]: position
Out[60]: array([1, 0, 6, 8, 1, 7, 1, 3, 1, 6])

In [61]: axis = 6

In [62]: mask = np.in1d(np.arange(position.size),axis)

In [63]: plus, minus = position + mask, position - mask

In [64]: plus
Out[64]: array([1, 0, 6, 8, 1, 7, 2, 3, 1, 6]) # Change at 6th index

In [65]: minus
Out[65]: array([1, 0, 6, 8, 1, 7, 0, 3, 1, 6]) # Change at 6th index
```

Comment: Instinctively, I thought you'd cheated by using `np.arange(position.size)` ! This is in fact a very good solution and **exactly** what I was after. *Although just combining them in a tuple is definitely cheating in my books as we may as well use a semicolon! (:* - Also I like the use of boolean logic nice thinking outside the box

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Well, if you are that strict, you can do `position + np.in1d(np.arange(position.size),axis)` and `position - np.in1d(np.arange(position.size),axis)`. But that's a bit redundant code. So, you know :)

Comment: touché: To strictly fulfil the *two lines* requirement you had a choice of inefficient code or sneaky shortcuts. I suspected it might be bad code to write into two lines but I wanted the solution to be in-place as you managed so thanks !

Comment: @AlexanderMcFarlane Ah also, if it's just one index, you can just do `np.arange(position.size) == axis` to get the mask. The advantage with `np.in1d` would be that you can specify more than one element as indices in `axis`.